# i want to write a hyperlink between table row and table data in out,println statement (servlet) but i cant

Tags: servlets

out.print(" "++""+rs3.getInt(1)+""+rs3.getString(2)+""+rs3.getString(3)+""+rs3.getString(4)+""+rs3.getString(5)+" "+rs3.getString(6)+""+rs3.getString(7)+""+rs3.getString(8)+"");

Comment: please dont tell my formatting mistake  you can just help me by answering how to write href tag  between tr and td !!!!!

Comment: There isn't nearly enough information to answer this.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you are trying to achieve something like this in servlet....

```
<html>
<body>
<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <td> <a href="link/to/another/page" >LinkToAnotherPage</a> </td>
        <td> <a href="link/to/another/page" >LinkToAnotherPage</a> </td>
        <td> <a href="link/to/another/page" >LinkToAnotherPage</a> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

then,in servlet,its quivalent will be...

```
String myPath="link/to/another/page";
out.print("<table border='1'> <br>" );
out.print("<tr> <br>");
out.print("<td> <a href='"+myPath+"'>LinkToAnotherPage </a> </td>");
out.print("<td> <a href='"+myPath+"'>LinkToAnotherPage </a> </td>");
out.print("</tr> </table> </body> </html>");
```

Notice   **'** and **"** after `href=`.